# Accessing a persistent ssh tunnel

Tags: bash, ssh

How do I pass commands (shell) to a persistent SSH tunnel rather than open a connection for every instance? I have a Python scraper running on a client server which passes URL variables and shell commands to a remote host via a reverse tunnel (forwarded port),  so that the URL's are then executed on the host (python > fabric > ssh localhost:12345 'browser open URL'). I could make the reverse tunnel persistent but how do I *echo* the url/command to the session?

Update - ControlMaster (built into SSH) solves this one.

Comment: when you say 'commands' do you mean shell commands, or is the command itself the URL in question (eg: its just data)? are you connecting to a server-side service using ssh as your carrier, or are you just executing shell commands as part of an ssh session?

Comment: I found what I was looking for, for now (see below). In response it's a shell command, sent to the host through SSH, in this example `ssh -p 00000 localhost 'DISPLAY=:0.0 firefox %s' %URL`. I'm still learning to walk and I don't think using SSH will be the best way as things get heavier so any suggestions are appreciated. But for now this works and saves messing about with queues.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered ControlMaster which is built into later SSH versions and reuses existing connections if they exist:

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-faster-connections.html

Great stuff. I might look into proxies and what not when things get a bit heavier so any advice on developing this is appreciated.